# How to configure Failover ip with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu

I have taken a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VPS from OVH i installed LEMP on it (Nginx , Mysql, Php). Original IP of my Server is 217.182.xxx.xxx which is working fine. I have purchased extra ip (Failover IP) to host my second website on it.

Secondary IP (Failover IP): 51.38.xxx.xxx

I have tried a lot to configure this Failover ip on my vps. I have followed a lot of articles available on internet but not able to fix the issue.

**GOAL :** I want "while putting my FAILOVER ip address in browser it should reflect content hosted on my VPS" as it is showing for "217.182.xxx.xxx" This VPS ip.

I have followed [this](https://www.ovh.com/world/g2043.configure_a_failover_ip_with_ubuntu) OVH article too.

My Network Interface File:

```
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 51.38.xxx.xxx
netmask 255.255.255.255
broadcast 51.38.xxx.xxx
```

While i tried to restart network services, I got the following error.

```
root@vps540536:~# service networking restart
```

[image: See This Error Snap Shot]

Answer (score 0):

Configration looks good. 
Did you tried to reboot the machine?

In my situation, it was the assigned virtuall mac address to the ip. I removed the virtuell mac and it worked.